# Gson Custom deserializer

Tags: gson

I want to deserialize json string to java object. My class structure is this

```
public class Category {
String name;
int id;
ArrayList<Catalog> catalogs;
}
```

and catalog class structure is this

```
public class catalog {
private int catalogId = 0;
private String catalogName;
}
```

Following code i used to deserialize

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

 ArrayList<Category> categories = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Category.class);
```

I got exception when it try to deserialize ArrayList catalogs;

If i remove ArrayList then it parse successfully

Thanks
Pawan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The problem is that the string which i am parsing contain boolean value instead of Array . So There is exception while parsing.

The reason is that datatype is not match in json string which is parsed.

Thanks